# PHP check input type for validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm wondering if there is a way to check what type of input was used for $_POST information. I want to then use that type for validation. For instance, if an input type="text" then I would want to be able to create certain validations for that type of input.

So this is my code to generate the form:

```
$fields = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Name:',
        'id' => $meta.'_nhm_lead_name',
        'class' => 'field-name input', // optional
        'wrapper_class' => 'four columns', // optional
        'type' => 'text',
        'required' => true,
    ),
)
```

and this is how I generate the html:

```
    public function make_fields(){
    foreach($this->fields as $field => $value){
        switch ($value['type']) {
            case 'text':
                $inputs .= '<li class="field '.$value['wrapper_class'].'">';
                $inputs .= '<input type="text" name="'.$value['id'].'" class="'.$value['class'].'" />';
                $inputs .= '<span class="error-message"></span>';
                $inputs .= '</li>';
            break;
         }
     } 
     }
```

Comment: Use a client side validator like jQuery Validate.

Comment: No. The client side is waaay to easy to manipulate. I would never use it...

Comment: No, but you already know it since you wrote it, so you can write the server-side validation

Comment: No @scrowler Please no.

Comment: you should validate according to the intended input certain text inputs may need extra constrains than others

Comment: does it really matter? You don't validate based on client-side types, you validate based on what you expect that particular field name to contain. A date entered into `<input type="text"` is going to be the same whether it was `text` or a `date`-type.

Comment: @qwertynl Agreed, thats why I'm trying to avoid using client side validation. Especially because this form needs to be backwards compatible as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Input is text.maybe you want http://www.php.net/is_numeric

Comment: I really do not know what you want to do @CarlosRios ...

Comment: your idea doesn't seem to be a good approach for validating

Comment: @MarcB normally thats what i would do, this form is much different as it is going to be used on many projects, and I can't go and rewrite the validation for each of the projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When receiving the data from $_POST only the values are passed. However, you can use an structure like this:

```
$Fields = array( 
  array('type' => 'text',   'name' => 'name'),
  array('type' => 'text',   'name' => 'password'),
  array('type' => 'number', 'name' => 'age'));
```

Then generate the html form from that. So then, you can use that same variable to generate the validation. However, this is normally too much work for few forms (engine to generate form inputs from an array), and it's preferred to make it 'hardcoded' unless you are using already a framework with this functionality.

To give you an idea, the form would be like:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "/post.php">
  <?php foreach ($Fields as $Input) {
    switch($Input['type']) {
      case "text": 
        echo "<input type = 'text' name = '" . $Input['name'] . "'>";
        break;
      case "number":
        echo "<input type = 'number' name = '" . $Input['name'] . "'>";
        break;
      }
    }
   ?>
 </form>
```

And then in `post.php`:

```
foreach ($Fields as $Input) {
  $Name = $Input['name'];
  if (array_key_exists($Name, $_POST) &&
      // You need to define this:
      checktype($_POST[$Name], $Input['type'])) {
    $Posted = $_POST[$Name];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing. Here is an example of the array I use to generate the html:

                $fields = array(
  array(
   'label' => 'Name:',
   'id' => $meta.'_nhm_lead_name',
   'class' => 'field-name input', // optional
   'wrapper_class' => 'four columns', // optional
   'type' => 'text',
   'required' => true,
  ),

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure why it isn't displaying as code, but thats the general idea of what I'm using

Comment: There's no enter in the comments nor 'proper code', you can do only one-lines. I'll try to decypher it (; However you might want to put that in your OP so others know what you've done so far.

Comment: Then what's the problem? Why are you asking your original question if you already have this?

Comment: The problem is that I want to validate it based on the input type. I think thats what your example of post.php does right?

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind that it has probably several bugs (not tested) and that you have to define checktype for each form type and a case for each input type; that's why I said that this is normally *hardcoded*, since it's too much effort/time for so little.

Comment: Yes I agree, it would be much easier to hardcode each variable you're trying to validate. I saw it done in a way with Gravity forms for Wordpress and thought it would be neat to implement in my plugin as well. I'll try to define checktype in my Class and see if I can get that going. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If it's for a plugin it should be good. Please comment back with a link to the code when you have it if you decide to make it open source, it sounds interesting (:

Comment: Will do. It'll be the first thing I put out there and it is going to be open source. Without giving too much away, I'm trying to create a WP post, and add metadata to the post at the same time. All this will be done by users in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do that based on the name of the key in the $_POST array.  A user can submit data without using any type (Javascript for example) making what you are asking to do impractical.  They would be sending data that had no type.

Data being posted to your page can come from anywhere.

For re-usability, create a data object for the submission of your form that contains the validations for each of the inputs or write a validation function.  Keep that on the server so that a malicious user isn't able to manipulate the data and change how you validate what is being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a jQuery script that checks the `prop` of the input, and then adds it to the `$_POST`.  Something like:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action = "here.php" id="myform">
   <input type="text" value="hello" id= "input1" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
var input1type="&input1type=" + $('#input1').prop('type');
$.post('here.php', $('#myform').serialize()+input1type );
```

This would be best used if you can't affect the originating HTML.

Please note, that this is dangerous, and you can't trust the data from the www, but it might work in a secured (such as intranet) system.