# Detect type value fields from post form

Tags: php, forms

I want know, if it´s possible detect when use POST in form, the  value of **type** for each input field.

**For example** :

```
<input type="text" name="phone" value="Phone">
<input type="password" name="pass" value="Password">
```

I can get value and name for each input field, but, ..... how i can show for each field if **type** it´s text or password, as in this case

This it´s my question, because i can´t find some solution for this, howewer with jquery but no using php for get results from post form, and i need get this using php

**Thank´s in advance**

Comment: Impossible, The types are more for browsers, not for PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP check input type for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481578/php-check-input-type-for-validation)

Comment: No duplicate and not the same because in this link you put this guy insert the type as text in function and here i need detect when send post, it´s different

Comment: It's a duplicate as your questions are the same in essence and the answer to your question is No.

Comment: If these inputs are static, you already know the types. So why you need to detect? If you need a work around, maybe you need to explain more.

Comment: Not the same in function in this url this guy send text type or password type and indicate the kind type, in my case the script need detect the type and never indicate in function in preview function or class, this it´s not true, no duplicate

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't receive this information. You'll need to find a workaround for what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just Using PHP you can't do that. You Need to use javascript for that

- Instead of direct form submit onclick of submit you can call a javascript function
- In that function create a array of json with field type, field name and field value data
- Now post JSON data using ajax or javascript XMLHTTP Request to PHP

. .